# Perform actions on a table in a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, table

I can't find a solution to resolve this problem. I have this table:

```
<table>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.fixedDocs}" var="docs" indexVar="index">
                <tr>
                    <td><aura:text aura:id="nomeDoc" value="{!docs.Label}"/></td>
                    <td><aura:text aura:id="tipo" value="{!docs.Document_Type__c}"/></td>
                    <td><aura:text aura:id="stato" value="{!docs.State__c}"/></td>
                    <td><aura:text aura:id="firmatari" value="{!docs.Firmatari__c}"/></td>
                    <td><lightning:input aura:id="file" type="file" label=" " name="file" multiple="false" accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx" onchange="{!c.save}"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <lightning:button class="deleteButtons" label="" iconName="utility:delete" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.deleteRow}"/>
                        <lightning:button class="saveButtons" variant="brand" label="" iconName="utility:download" iconPosition="left"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration> 
</table>
```

In the last column I have two buttons, one to delete the row and the other to save the information.
How can figure out which row is interested in the action?
I tried to assign the `index` variable to the lable and to aura:id of the button so later I could know which row is interested but these attribute don't support expressions and so I can assign to them only a static string.
How can I resolve that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may use `tabindex` to get index from `Lighting:button`

```
<lightning:button tabindex="{!index}" class="deleteButtons" label="del" iconName="utility:delete" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.deleteRow}"/>
```

**In controller**

```
  deleteRow:function (component, event, helper) {
         console.log("Check",event.getSource().get("v.tabindex"));
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much man. You save my *** for the second time! Vote my question, please.

Answer (score 1):

I agree aura:id does not take any expressions, however the other html attributes would take, So a simple way would be to use "label" to hold your ids.

```
<td>
    <lightning:button class="deleteButtons" label="{!doc.Id}" iconName="utility:delete" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.deleteRow}"/>
    <lightning:button class="saveButtons" variant="brand" label="" iconName="utility:download" iconPosition="left"/>
</td>
```

Notice that label = {!doc.Id}, we can get them through event.getSource()

Your click handler will be as follows

```
deleteRow : function(component, event, helper){
    var source = event.getSource(); // this would give that particular component
    var recordId = source.get("v.label"); // returns the id
    /* Make the server side action with this recordId as a parameter */
}
```

I dont think there is a force:deleteRecord yet something similar to force:createRecord event, hence you might have to call the @Aura-Enabled methods to do the delete.

Comment: No, I've already written that this doesn't work. I think that all attributes of lightning component can't contains dynamic content.

Comment: Hmm .. labels are supposed to work AFAIK .. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm

Comment: And if lighnting component attributes does not take expression. Then i guess we will have to go for slds-buttons (custom markup )

Comment: Neither because with Locker Service you don't target element with `document.getElementById()` or other similar methods.